# Add a value to each element in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a good way to add a certain value to each element in an array in javascript? Essentially, this should be a better way of writing the following:

```
      a = [1,2,3,4];
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          a[i] += 7;
      }
```

Maybe using map (but not necessarily)?

Edit:

Or a more interesting example:

```
      a = [{'x':1},{'x':2},{'x':3},{'x':4}];

      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          a[i].x += 7;
      }
```

Comment: In reality, either way you are doing the same thing.

Comment: But in less (code) space!! Hopefully :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use `map` to do it:

```
a = a.map(function(entry) {
    return entry + 7;
});
```

I'm not seeing how it's "better" to create a new array rather than update the one you have.

You can also use `forEach`:

```
a.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    a[index] += 7;
});
```

It's still a bunch of function calls (but [that's not a problem](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html)), but you have the advantage (over a `for` loop) of not having to declare the indexing variable, and you're modifying the existing array rather than replacing it.

---

Edit: Your "most interesting" example says even more that `map` is not really the best choice.

```
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.x += 7;
});
```

Comment: `forEach` appears to be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `.map` but it will not modify the array in-place, so you must assign the result to `a`:

```
a = a.map(function(x) { return x+7 });
```